# Can LiveCode recognise the characters that I draw?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, livecode

I want my app to be able to recognise characters that I draw on screen, but I really don't know where to start - is there an external, etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some basic character recognition for my 'Spell With Kyle' app.  It currently only recognises one character at a time, but the idea could be worked on if you need something more complex. There's an explanation of the technique and an example stack at http://splash21.com/Gestures.html

HTH  :D

(It's just LiveCode - no external)

Comment: that's great - thanks for the example.  Could I make it recognize whole words?

Comment: it's possible - you'd need to recognise when each character begins/ends.  You could try matching characters as the user draws...